# Does cycles allow for negative values in color data?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, image, color-management

I was recently working on a node setup the required for some color image data to have some negative values, as I was using the subtract node. As far as I can tell, the values stop being subtracted at 0 though, and just flatten out. I turned clamping off on *all* of the nodes too. Would a good (but slightly painful) work around be to separate the R, the G and the B values into value data instead of color?

Please site a manual source if possible.

Comment: It [works for me](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39490)..?

Comment: I think your suggestion to split the channels into value data would be better regardless of whether this might work - colors aren't meant to be negative, since such a thing doesn't really exist. It would therefore also just be more transparent if you were to separate the values. You could, I guess, work with a Point3 or Point4 value instead, if you really want to perform operations on all three or four channels at once.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, but this one is going through a bunch of MixRGB nodes set to various values, and is being used in the world material. I think something is chopping the values.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms without seeing the structure of your nodes, the best I can guess is that the mixRGB operation is performing an operation that requires the values to be within RGB range, being 0-255. Could you try splitting up the values / using a Point3 and see if that changes anything?

Comment: @MaVCArt I conducted a quick test, and the negative values do in fact appear to be working, something else in the node tree was throwing me off.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26271/7777