# Background plate for interior render with windows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hdri

I'm making an interior scene in Blender (you can check it below) using two light sources. One sun lamp and an environment hdr image.

[image]

I'm happy with the result but I need to have something outside the window. It can be a city landscape for example. But looking at renders on the internet, I always see these kind of interior scenes with an overexposed light coming from the window.

Either way, what is the correct way to make this render better? If it's with a plate, how can I do it in order not to block the sun lamp?

Thanks.

Comment: you can also use compositing to show a background image.

Comment: I have to try that, yes. For now I'm having that issue and also problems with lighting. Because it's an interior and I have only those windows, everything closer to the camera has a lot of issues.

Comment: There are many ways to make a background that is not too bright. What will make your render **"better"** will mean different things for every one... You can  have a plane with an image used as texture in a different layer, that is not lit by your "sun" lamp. You can composite a background in the compositor . You can even use a different HDR and use light paths to make it visible to camera but not take part on the lighting of the scene. If your issue is with the brightness of the image used in the world settings, then try rendering with a wider dynamic range using Filmic Blender.

Comment: Thanks cegaton, for your help. I'm using Filmic already. The hdr I have has strength 35 and my sun has strength 15. Maybe these values are not the best ones. Also, the measurements of the scene are real. So, 1 blender unit is 1meter (don't know if this has some influence). I will try to use a background image with the light path.

Comment: use the False Color view in the color management settings, it will allow you to dial the brightness values. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56267/how-to-scale-properly-hdri-image-to-be-used-in-asc-cdl-hdr-render

Comment: I will. What about the problem of the not so light areas (near the camera)? I have no other way to get a nice render unless I add more lights to the scene? Or remove the back walls for this particular render? What is the correct way to do it? For now I'm rendering a still image but If I need to do an animation I can't just delete geometry.