# White background with filmic blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, filmic-blender

When I tried rendering the scene with white background in filmic blender, I'm getting grey coloured background. But I'm able to achieve this with standard colour management options.

P.s: I have edited light source to match the filmic blender.

Comment: @cegaton thanks for the prompt response. I was able to achieve it by increasing the intensity

Comment: @pycoder I was able to achieve the desired​results by increasing the intensity of the light source

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Filmic blender uses  a different scale than sRGB, it is designed for a much wider dynamic range, so to get white it is necessary to increase the intensity of the light for that background.

The standard sRGB transform will display "white" when the scene values reach a value of **1**

[image]

Using the filmic blender transforms, you need a much higher value. "White" is at a value of **16.19**.

[image]

To visualize how the scene referred values are being mapped using the filmic blender you can use the false colour view transform.

To understand what filmic blender does and how it maps the scene's values to the displayed image please read the following link: [Render with a wider dynamic range in cycles to produce photorealistic looking images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im)

and https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender

Answer (score -1):

This compositing node setup produce 100% white on transparent channel with filmic color management:
[image: Node setup]

Note that in the color balance node, "Correction Formula" has to be set to "Offset/Power/Slope (ASC-CDL)" and also the grey scale faders all have to be set to 100% white.

This setup is also work:
[image: Node setup v2]

Comment: The problem I see with this answer is that you might end up pushing the values to a point that is way beyond "white". White in filmic is at a value of 16.19 roughly, any value larger than that will be ignored or "clipped". Also, using the CDL with no regard to the numbers used for Offset Power and Slope might lead to unwanted values for the rest of the scene. To understand how to use the CDL read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/what-is-the-the-asc-cdl-node

Comment: At least he was trying to actually explain how to perform a solution to the asker. BTW, this doesn't work in Blender 2.91

Comment: For use this setup in 2.91, EVEE or Сycles, need to set in shader editor, world section background color alpha channel to zero. With render properties, film transparent checkbox, of course.