# Shadow very suppressed in compositor when goes against background

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

For some reason my render in the compositor is all weird.
Here's the problem: the background is not completely white and the shadows get suppressed.

If I render everything without the background image so it is transparent then put it in Photoshop and add a white image everything works fine but why does it not work in Blender?

**EDIT:** I was aware of the color values where 1 was not pure white anymore but I thought it might be relevant so I left it there. The real main issue is the shadow being suppressed by the background. Again, when transparent it is fantastic but as the value of the background goes higher, it fades away till it just disappears completely.

That is my main issue.

Example:

In Blender: [image]

in photoshop: [image]

I could show you my compositor setup but its basically just Alpha Over with the background being the same white image I used from photoshop.

Just in case if you guys really need to see the render setup then its pretty long so bear with me here: [image][image]

Any help is honestly greatly appreciated because I am really stuck here..
Thanks!

Comment: What settings are you using in the color management section?

Comment: Fantastic question I didn't even think about it!

[I am using this:](https://i.imgur.com/HRyBzDj.png)

Comment: Filmic blender needs to be used correctly, is not a magic button. Keep in mind that what you call "pure white" is no longer a value of RGB 1,1,1 but a much larger number. Place the values for "white" on RGB 17,17,17 and see the difference. Please read:  [Render with a wider dynamic range in cycles to produce photorealistic looking images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White background with filmic blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender)

Comment: I thought so too. I put the value to something way higher so I got complete white but the shadows are still all messed up. I thought the high value might've been the issue

Comment: Thank you very much I will read up on this and come back if it fixed the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: @Lambdadelta Sadly I believe there is no solution. Like was mentioned above by cegaton, because of the way that Filmic Blender works, having a complete white is achievable but will affect the rest of the image. 

The only workaround I found was to render the scene with a transparent background, then add a white layer in the back in Photoshop.