# Low contrast in grease pencil rendering

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

I was using the 2D animation environment to do a simple b/w drawing and when I press f12 to export I get a really low contrast image. Anyone knows whats happening?

[image: pre rendering canvas]

[image: rendering]

Comment: Most likely you have the color management set up for filmic blender. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender/78299#78299

Comment: set the Display transform in color management to sRGB