# Why does a white background look grey once added to the VSE as a scene strip?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

[image: Grease Pencil Image]

In Grease Pencil this is how the image looks with a nice white background.

[image: Video Sequencer image]

When the same is imported to video sequencer I get a solid grey background. I tried putting a white solid behind to see if there was any transparency issue but the grey remains.

I need a proper white background, how to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi. When you say "imported" to the video sequencer, do you mean as a scene strip or you rendered out the grease pencil animation and imported that?

Comment: Scene Strip, As I had also cut audio in video sequencer to use in 2D animation it was unwilling to render from GP only. Also I had to add scene and shot numbers. So I made a scene strip and in Video Editor>Add Scene.

Comment: The grease pencil works in display referred values, where 0 is black and 1 is white. When you use filmic as view transform in the color management, you are working in the wrong scale. Filmic works with values much larger than 1, white is at a value of 16.2 approximately.

Answer (score 0):

A friend sorted it out for me. Color Management was the issue. In Video Editing>Render Properties>Color Management>View Transform> Change it from default Filmic to Standard.

Pls don't ask in detail what Filmic is etc, I don't understand.

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender

Answer (score -1):

This could be a few things;

1. if you go to the world tab and click the colour property make sure the value is set to 1 ( by default my blender starts-up with 0.8). For pure white mine is H0 S0 V1 A1.
2. do you have any lights in the scene?
3. do you have any special effects?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: The wold tab setting is pure white at strength 1. There are no lights, no SFX used it is just drawings.

Comment: I just changed the world color at random yellow, but when I see the same strip in video editor it is still grey. It does not come out as yellow

Comment: Are you able to share your blend file for us to have a look?

Comment: Sorry, it is a comissioned project.