# Pure white background + filmic + antialiasing: is it possible?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management, filmic-blender

I'm trying to achieve an image with a pure white background. Apart from the grey background, I'm more or less happy with it so far:

[image]

This is using Filmic, and I understand the reason for the grey background. I don't want to blow out the highlights in those transparent objects, so my goal is to composite this image onto a pure white background.

To try and achieve this, I enabled "transparent" under "film" in render properties, and then set up compositing like this

[image]

So I'm compositing with a white background, boosting its value up to 512 so that it will come out as pure white.

The problem is that the antialiasing looks pretty terrible. I've zoomed in a bit so you can see it:

[image]

I guess this is because it's still in the Filmic colour space when it's doing the antialiasing, so the antialiased pixels are just getting blown out along with the background.

This isn't really what I want to do. Ideally, I want to switch into a linear colour space and do the antialiasing there. I still want the render to be done in Filmic, but I want the compositing to be done in sRGB.

Is it possible to do that? Or is there another good way to get a pure white background on this image, without blowing out the detail or having aliasing around the edges?

(I realise I could just switch the whole thing into sRGB and re-tune everything to get a similar look. But this seems a step backwards. I like the way Filmic looks in general, and I want to stay in it for the rendering if I can.)

Comment: you don't need a value of 512. "White" is approximately at a value of 16.19

Comment: @susu thank you! I just found that 16.19 number somewhere else, and indeed it produces a pure white background with much better antialiasing. I am not sure where I got 512 from.

Comment: You got it from a **misinformed answer** on this site. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender. Also you don't need a color mix or a multiply node, just use a Input >  RGB node and imput the value manually

Comment: It should composite perfectly fine assuming you’re alpha is encoded correctly. How is the AA being derived? The issue may be the AA itself. Check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using filmic blender, "White" is at a value of 16.19 aproximately, there is no need to push it past that number, as it might lead you to other problems, like the one you are experiencing.

[image]