# Color sliders on vertical color bar rapidly scale from 0 to 40 instead of normally 0 to 1.0, how to fix this?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, color

for example, adjusting the color sliders on a point source light, you can use use the horizontal slider fine, but on the vertical color picker, it shoots from 0 to 40 and doesn't preview any colors except white on the bar. How can I fix the behavior to normal again where I can see a color gradient on it with values properly scaling from 0 to 1.0? Attached example

[image]

Comment: What Blender version is that? - I've never seen that happen on a color picker so it may be a bug. Also, where has the outlined "C" come from on the R/H end of the color bar below the picker? I've never seen that either.

Comment: This is K-Cycles build of Blender, 3.2. Slider always worked properly until I guess some addons recently. I'm trying to figure out what changed and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR: The answer

I guess the answer to your specific question is simply... Decrease the value by either dragging or clicking and typing, to a value within the $[0..1]$ range. I know, you can't go back in time and un-see it, the world will never be the same now.

### Blender values have two types of limits

- **Hard limits** - if you input something above the maximum, it will be set to that maximum instead; if you input something below the minimum, it will be set to that minimum; it's called clamping:

[image]

- **Soft limits** - these can't go beyond the hard limits. When you use your mouse to change the value, and the value is within the soft limits, dragging the value or clicking on arrow buttons, will not allow you to go beyond those limits. However, you can still type a value beyond the soft limit. Once you do, and end up outside the soft limits, you can now use your mouse to increase the value further above the soft limit (so the soft limit is like a single boundary, once crossed, the mouse is no longer constrained):

[image]

Notice how once you're above the maximum soft limit, you still can't drag the value below the minimum soft limit, because you would have to cross the boundary. However, you can go back and pass the maximum soft limit, because Blender remembers you started dragging beyond the maximum soft limit, and allows the mouse to restore the starting value.

Another interesting thing about soft limits is that for many fields they adjust automatically: for example color values are constrained to:

- $[0..1]$ range

but once you go slightly above that, e.g. $1.1$, they become constrained to

- $[0..2]$ range

with the next soft value ranges being:

- $[0..5]$
- $[0..10]$
- $[0..20]$
- $[0..50]$
- $[0..100]$
- $[0..200]$
- $[0..500]$
- $[0..1000]$
- $[0..2000]$
- $[0..5000]$

...And so on, it seems to follow a pattern typical for coin/banknote values.

Not everyone knows, color values in shaders are simply arrays of 3 float32 values, just like vectors. This means that each RGB color component can have any value in range:

$$-3.4028235e+38 .. +3.4028235e+38$$
or between $-340282349999999991754788743781432688640$ and $+340282349999999991754788743781432688640$

Though those min and max values will (incorrectly) display as `-inf` and `+inf`.

Additionally, color inputs will not allow you to input values below 0 - so the minimum hard limit is 0, but only for the inputs - the colors can still use negative values, you just need use a any other socket type, that doesn't have this limitation, and connect it via a link:

[image]

The above setup will produce a material that will absorb more red light than what the material settings (default specularity) allow. The animation below shows how an object with specularity `0.5` can become darker than black, and how some values will produce glitches in the form of very bright edges:

[image]

In general, color values outside of the $[0..1]$ range are strongly discouraged in realistic rendering, because such values in physical terms mean that the material bounces more light than it receives (or absorbs more light than it receives - in case of negative values) - it breaks the conservation of energy. However, for non-photorealistic rendering and just for dirty hacks, a common example of a value above 1 for color is $16.19$, which is required in *Filmic* color space to produce a full white #FFFFFF color. Let's set this cube's left side to $(1, 1, 1)$, and right side to $(16.19, 16.19, 16.19)$:

[image]

[Pure white background + filmic + antialiasing: is it possible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/186657/60486)