# Glow effect with multiple render layers not working

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I'm trying to composite 2 layers with different colours, each with a glow effect.  Unfortunately, when I combine them it produces a render that is way too bright and drowns out the colours of each layer.  I've tried add, mix, screen and alpha over but nothing seems to work.  How can I composite these while preserving their colours?

Here's the first layer:

[image]

Here's the second:

[image]

This is what happens when they're combined:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you are **adding** the information of two layers, once the values of the layers are equal or greater than one then they will be displayed as white. I can think of two options: 1: Work with a [much wider dynamic range](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im) or 2.-bring the layers to be added to a lower value so that they do not become one. You can use the CDL node (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/). Bring down the slope values the images before adding them together.

Comment: Hmm I tried using Filmic and it didn't really change anything even with all of the view settings.  Also tried using the CDL and colour management nodes but that didn't work either.  What ends up happening is it desaturates the composite and looks more like noodles that don't glow.