# Blender linear tone mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am currently using blender and would like to tone map an HDR. After researching this I found that there is a Tone mapping node : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/tone_map.html 
How can I use the node to tone map linearly?

Comment: I think you may need to fiddle around with the settings under Color Management in the scene tab to get a linear output. Not sure what the correct settings to use are though. .

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "tone map linearly"?

Comment: Also look into the [ASC-CDL node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/what-is-the-the-asc-cdl-node)