# How do I adjust for overexposure using physically based lighting?

Tags: lighting, color-management, filmic-blender

I am trying to get my head around physically based lighting in Blender.

I read somewhere the Cycles Sun Lamp is measured in W/m² so
assuming that bright sunlight is measured at 120000 lux (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight) my intensitiy for the blender sun will be (given that 1lux = 0.0079 W/m2 for sunlight) around 980 W/m². This matches more or less with the readings from wikipedia, that states that the max sun intensity depending on its distance from the earth is 1050 W/m² (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight).

Using the filmic Blender add-on I am now way overexposed. 
Here comes my first question: where do I compensate for that? I found two exposure sliders within Blender. One directly in the color management tab, which I assume doesn't affect the final rendering, but only the viewport lut. Or do I use the exposure slider under the render tab/film?

Second: How does cycles handle the light contribution from environment maps? In what relation do they stand to the sun intensity as they have a seperate intensity slider. Is there a rule of thumb to get them in the right ballpark?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. You are welcome to ask as many separate questions as you need as separate posts.

Comment: please split this post in two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the false colour look in combination with a CDL node ([What is the the ASC-CDL node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/what-is-the-the-asc-cdl-node)) to bring your values within the range of the color transform.

See also this related post: [How to scale properly HDRI image, to be used in ASC-CDL HDR render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56267/how-to-scale-properly-hdri-image-to-be-used-in-asc-cdl-hdr-render)

and this one (somehow outadted, but should give you an idea): [Using the False Color look in combination with the CDL Node to work on Wide Dynamic Range scenes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55859/using-the-false-color-look-in-combination-with-the-cdl-node-to-work-on-wide-dyna)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53155/how-must-i-adapt-my-workflow-to-work-with-scene-referred-data/53161#53161 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender/66600#66600

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13678/which-exposure-control-to-use