# How do I output to HDR10 Movie format in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, file-format, color, hdri

Ok, so I have just purchased an [HDR10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_video#HDR10) compatible 3840*2160 Display (4K), and I want to render some videos in Blender to look at in full HDR10 glory on it.

However it's Roku TV based OS has limitations regarding what file formats it can take, the supported file formats and codecs are listed in the image below:

[image: Supported File formats]

However, in my searches, no one has been able to answer how to *output* to an HDR *video* format (TIFF can output to 16-bit RGBA, but TIFF does not work on the TV), everyone has how to input and manipulate HDR content inside of Blender and render that as the background.

Can anyone please figure out how to output to an HDR10 video in of Blender, I know that resolution doesn't really matter, but I specifically want the colors to be of HDR10. (the TV plays 720p HDR10 footage from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tO01J-M3g0U) just fine, so you do not have to worry about resolution issues)

(And for anyone wondering, the TV model is the TCL 55s401, and its spec sheet can be found [here](https://www.tclusa.com/sites/default/files/2017-04/S401%20Spec%20Sheets.pdf), also if you want to see some actual HDR content that works on this TV, almost all the videos in this [zip](https://mega.nz/#F!jYwlgbBA!piXwD8sYa7zjsRtjStuAyw) do run on this TV as well).

Comment: I'm not even sure Blender supports any HDR video format, as far as I know. Only HDR based static dimage file formats life OpenEXR and Multilayer EXR

Comment: You would also need to create a definition in the OCIO color management files, with a color matrix to get the proper color transform from 709 color space to 2020, export then image sequence in TIFF 16bit log, and encode in an external program that can do proper h.64 at 10 bit and encode to the proper flavor of HDR. Most likely you could do this in DaVinci Resolve.  An alternative would be to export as EXR and import into DaVinci and encode and do the color space transformation there.

Comment: Is there a way to contact Blender Team and ask for HDR in the next major release, 2.80?

Comment: you could put a request over here : https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Answer (score 3):

While Blender supports rendering in wide-dynamic range (32bit float) [scene-referred](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53155/how-must-i-adapt-my-workflow-to-work-with-scene-referred-data) files, as of v3.6 Blender lacks the ability to save these in a format most HDR displays and video players will accept as input. You can save OpenEXR sequences from Blender to create a finished HDR video in other software such as DaVinci Resolve.

It is possible to export 16bit TIFFs from Blender that are already formatted for HLG or HDR10 PQ with the help of an OpenColorIO configuration such as ACES by using one of the appropriate HDR ODTs such as "Rec. 2020 ST2084 1000 nits". For more information on ACES in Blender, see this question [Using Blender with wider gamut than 709 primaries (like ACES)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173582/using-blender-with-wider-gamut-than-709-primaries-like-aces) You will still need additional software to convert to a 10bit HEVC/VP9/AV1 video file and apply the relevant metadata so that players and TVs will recognize it properly. This can be done with FFMPEG however instead of needing something like Resolve, or by using one of the many frontends for FFMPEG. Note that many more common FFMPEG frontends (such as Handbrake) do not support 10bit encoding or adding the HDR10/HLG metadata. Staxrip and Hybrid are examples of frontends that can do the job.

Encoding Dolby Vision is significantly more complicated and building the final playback file requires some special tools and licenses that most people do not have access to.