# I have rendered my Blender Intro and it saved as a .avi file but I cant open it?

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I have rendered my intro as an animation and it has saved as a .avi file in a folder but I can't open it. What can I Do? I have tried different media files and everything. Help please!

Comment: Likely a bad combination of container formats and video codecs. Not much you can do other that re-render the animation with different settings if no player can read it. It has been stated countless times before: NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER render a 3D animation directly to a video format, always frames to image files

Comment: @Mattewh: it should be a codec/container bad choice: please report what settings you had, and what are you using to test the video. Saving to image sequence would save some time if you need to retry many times, but the best is to find out best setting with a simple,fast "default cube" animation, and then save those settings for bigger projects....

Answer (score 2):

Try rendering as png sequence images then editing them together in the Video sequence editor... this way you can try different formats without having to render all the work again ;-)

Comment: Or better, *avoid PNG's at all costs*, and render to a post production-friendly format such as Half EXR or Full. ;)

Comment: Why isn't png so recommendable? In which ways is it exr more "production-friendly"?

Comment: 1. PNGs can only store unassociated alpha. 2. PNGs can only store display referred value ranges. There are other reasons, but those two alone make it absolutely worthless. To get a better handle on scene referred versus display referred, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Answer (score 2):

Blender uses [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to encode video, [vlc](http://videolan.org) or [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) would have the best chance of playing odd codec combinations.

You might have luck using [FFmpeg to convert](http://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/) the video with different settings, otherwise you will have to re-render with better encoding settings.

This is an example of why people recommend rendering to an image sequence and then using the VSE to create a video file, rendering is the most time consuming part, re-trying different video encoding options to convert an image sequence to video is faster than re-rendering to video.