# How to get rid of circular light lines

Tags: rendering, materials, light

I have this very simple render.[image]

If you see on the picture, there are circular light lines around the cube. Starting with the arrows and until the end of the light. I was wondering if there is a way to smooth these out so there are no lines.The plane is just a grey diffuse, and the light is and area light.

Comment: I can't see any lines or lighting, only a plain black background and JPEG compression artifacts which will only worsen diagnosing this. Could you clarify what you mean? How was the image produced? It looks like a viewport screenshot, was it rendered in Cycles, Internal?

Comment: Ah yes, I see them, it's just a gradient effect from the light dissipating the further you get from the source. A simple fix is to just increase the size of the light source in the properties panel. You may have to increase the intensity also but the increased size will project this gradient effect outside the camera's field of view.

Comment: Those lines are banding. The result of low bit depth: There are not enough bits to resolve the difference between very similar tones. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding. To avoid it you need to work at a higher bit depth (like 16 or 32 bits), but even then you might still see banding if your monitor is only capable of displaying 8 bit images. To make the issue less apparent you can increase the the values for **Dither** in the post processing section of the Properties panel. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/what-does-dither-do-in-cycles/5800#5800

Comment: Also worth reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65103/color-banding-in-blender-internal-render-output