# Render looks fine until saved (with a lossless image format), then it has colour banding

Tags: rendering

Thank you for the help. :)

I see no problems in the rendered image, but, when I save it as PNG or TIFF, I can see colour banding in the saved image. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74809/rendered-image-shows-visible-line-strokes-artefacts

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65103/color-banding-in-blender-internal-render-output