# How do I create realistic lighting emiting from a bulb from a lamp

Tags: materials, light

I am a noob at blender and I created this scene(work-in-progress), and the study Lamp will be the only light source.

[image]

However, the light is filling the room and doesn't look realistic.

I want the bulb in the lamp holder to only emit light at the table(directional) and I don't know how to achieve this. have a look at this image to know what I mean:

[image]

The bulb is only emitting light at the bottom and top(since it is open) and no light is emitted like in my image(except soft light)

In a nutshell, how do I make the bulb throw light only at the table, like a spotlight? I want the rays visible.

**EDIT: The first is my render. The second is an example image from google to better explain what I want.**

Comment: What type of Lamp are you using ? this is a job for Spot Lamp for it emit light in a cone shape.

Comment: maybe start with using a real light bulb ?

Comment: @Venay I am using a material to emit light. UV Sphere.

Comment: @OldMan i don't understand.

Comment: @4-K, UV sphere is good here in the principle. What is the issue exactly from that? Using Cycles, right?

Comment: And @OldMan is right: a lamp (point) is faster

Comment: Try moving the sphere further back in the lamp itself, and maybe scaling it down. Remember, the actual light emitter in a real-life bulb is rather small, so just experiment with it until you get satisfactory results.

Comment: @lemon Yes, Cycles. I want the light to only strike the table. Like the light effect from a torch. In my render the light is appearing to be emitted FROM the table and enlighting the whole room. There is no rays visible from the source.

Comment: @JoshSilveous The sphere is small and I have moved it farthest in the lamp. :(

Comment: First, make the world texture completely black, so that you have no "environment" lights. Then make the light surce a point light and make the size = zero. Then start bringing the intensity to a high value. For a realisitic look you might need to use the "Filmic Blender" http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Comment: @4-K Then I would recommend just changing the emitter to a standard light. Perhaps you could [provide us your .BLEND using this website](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? We could do some tinkering and see if we can figure out how to solve your problem

Comment: It worked now. I had to just turn off the environment light and move the sphere even further back up. Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a "point" light as lamp and a fabric texture with translucent shader for the lampshade.

[image]

The point light is just a light (as suggested by OldMan in the comments):

[image]

The lampshade is composed of a fabric texture and a translucent shader:

[image]

"No more"... if you try replacing the point lamp by a sphere, this is working too, but the render is slower and more noisy.

[image]

Comment: I would add to this response information about Filmic Blender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53m-17Y_zJg