# Rendered Shadow is not sharp

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am texturing leaves on planes and while rendering , it is generating blurry  shadows of the leave object. The same problem occurs with the other objects also.

[image]

Any recommended render settings for a sharper shadow?

Comment: What do you mean by correct shadow? Without even knowing light setup I could tell you that this one is correct. For some settings.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size/44725#44725 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows/77347#77347

Comment: What is the souce of lighting?if you are using sun, try set the size to zero..as i saw your final render was bit soft (size might be larger than 0)..hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your light source is too big. I can't see what you are using, but if you are looking for unrealistic hard shadows (usually caused by artificial lighting), you need to get a smaller light source. If you are using an area lamp, get the size of it down and turn the strength up. You could also use a point lamp instead. A plane using an emission shader? Make it bigger. If you are looking for natural lighting, this is pretty accurate. Some more rendering samples will reveal the true shape of the shadow.

Comment: Moreover, my object was away from the floor also.. Thanks it solved my problem..