# What lighting settings would be used to achieve colored and soft directional light

Tags: materials, light, shaders

In reference to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbCJKfol-WQ and here's a screenshot of the result:
[image]

The person that made the video said they didn't use any materials, it's just Blenders default diffuse and that all the color comes from the lighting. What lighting would be used to achieve this white paper effect?

Comment: Looks like a simple sun lamp with a pink-ish color tone and a large radius

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size/44725#44725 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows/77347#77347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not that much to this.
Any big light source with the color you want will do.

[image]

The bigger the light source the softer the shadows on the scene.