# How can i reduce the size of my shadows?

Tags: tracking, lighting, shadows, hdri, shadowcatcher

I am lighting my scene with an spherical environment map. As you can see in the image below, the shadows casted on my shadow catcher are way too big. How can i change this?

[image: r]

Comment: first make sure your background map is in hdri format. Then try adding a colorramp node and squeeze it, connecting it between the output of the map and the input of the background material.

Answer (score 1):

you could make it so that the background is not the light source with this node setup
[image][image]Then add a sunlamp, with it you can either increase your lamp's strength or decrease its size

A smaller lamp size will give a sharper shadow

[image]

then change it so it matches your background's color and thats it.

here is a more detailed answer to your questionn 
[How to minimize/soften the shadows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly your trick didn't really work. Now my scene is really dark and the shadows are still all over the place.