# how to remove the ugly shadow as shows in that photo?

Tags: shadows

[image]

I trying to put smooth shadow on my final render view like you you can see on the right.

Comment: Your scene needs more points of light. Add more area lights.

Comment: You don't necessarily need more lights, but larger lights (to make the shadows softer), and the lights could be brighter too. Read: [How to minimize or soften shadows](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows/77347#77347)