# background camera image over exposed

Tags: modeling

I used fspy to get my camera angle and then put my objects in the scene to have it appear over the image I took. And in the compositor tab, I used the alpha over to put the image behind my objects. For some reason though the image is now over exposed and I don't know if it causes of the sun I have, I guess, but I don't know. So I had to render just the 3d objects and import that into photoshop and put it over my image myself. Here are the images. I can't upload the blend file because the file is 211mb and the two sites I know that I can upload my blend file to have limits. The first image you can see is over exposed from blender, not the cubes though. The models are fine, it's the snail and the ground it's on that for some reason is different from the actual photo. The second image is what I did myself in photoshop. In the 3rd image, I'm kinda wondering if it has anything to do with the "color space" option to the image node. I've changed it to all the other options, and it doesn't look like the original photo still.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that you are using Filmic Color transform. It affects not only on render, but on the compositor images as well because it applied after all process (render and compositing). I know that it is very annoying, but I haven't found any solution to this case:

[How to mix a jpeg background image with a 3D scene generated using Filmic Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81433/how-to-mix-a-jpeg-background-image-with-a-3d-scene-generated-using-filmic-blende)

But you can disable Filmic if it is good for you:

[image]

Comment: That did it thank you, but I also had to change the look option from high contrast to none on top of what you suggested. I didn't realize that option would also affect the image node in the compositor tab in the final result.