# Match HTML colour in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, color, color-management, filmic-blender

I have rendered my Blender scene to an EXR. I want to composite this render over the top of a solid colour background. The background must exactly match a specific brand colour.

When using the "Filmic" view transform the render appears correctly, however the background isn't even close to the right colour. If I use the "Standard" view transform the background colour is correct, however the render looks awful.

The following image shows my compositing node setup:
[image: Compositing nodes]

Here is a comparison of "Standard" and "Filmic" versions. The highlights are horrible in "Standard", however the background colour is reproduced correctly:
[image: Standard vs filmic view transform]

How can I composite an image using one element that looks correct using "Filmic" and another that looks correct using "Standard"?

Comment: The only way I can think of now is to do the render separately and then do the compositing in a separate scene and/or blend file that is set to Standard view transform.

Comment: There is a Convert Colorspace node available but it only allows to switch between color spaces and not view transforms

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I'm doing the compositing in a separate file. I've tried using the "Convert Colorspace" node but I can't seem to find any way of converting sRGB to its filmic equivalent or filmic to standard.

Comment: You can't convert view transforms in compositing nodes. If you are doing the comp in a separate file everything should be OK. Do your render with filmic and then take the rendered image into another blend file set to standard and it will do the trick.

Comment: That works fine if I export as a PNG, JPEG etc. however rendering to EXR doesn't save the view transform. I need to use EXR as I have to preserve emissive materials etc. If I load the EXR for compositing in a project with a standard view transform it looks the same as if it were rendered with this transform.

Comment: You're right. I had to try it myself to see what you meant. You could create an image with just your background, import it as an image in your compositor and use the method stated here -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273382/115533

Comment: Good idea! It's a bit annoying having to save then open the image to change the background colour but at least it gives the correct result.