# What type of normal and specular map nodes is correct for these textures

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, normal-map

I am creating a plugin to import some model files from a game to blender, with all the textures and materials created automatically. I am creating a principled bsdf node from python and assign relevant textures to it depending on what I read.
However, I don't think the rendering result is correct, and I think that's due to the textures not being exactly what the shader inputs ask for.
For example, this is one material that is being created:
[image: material]

This is the original texture
[image: original tex]

This is the texture used for the Normal map
[image: normal map]

and this is the texture used for the Specular 
[image: specular map]

However, the result is too "shiny" and it seems very wrong to me
[image: render]
Is what I am doing at the moment the correct thing to do according to this specific texture types that I am having? Or do I need to add different nodes than those?

Comment: I added the original texture in the first post as well.
Those textures are from konami's game Pro Evolution Soccer, they were created by them and used in the game, im just creating a plugin to import their models (with all texture and material info) for blender.

Comment: The rendered image is of a stadium where the texture is for a door and an elevator door. Hard to tell what's wrong. Also, it seems your lights are too strong, making the scene overexposed.

Comment: lower the intensity of the  light or use a different color transform to have a wider dynamic range. Read:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Comment: Most of that is probably right.  Your "specular map" almost certainly should not be plugged into a specular node (or else it wouldn't be colored).  This may be a situation where it represents specular color, meaning that the principled shader is not an appropriate choice (cannot represent what you need to represent), but based off the texture, I think it's more likely that your specular map refers to multiple values in RGB channels.  Try separating the texture color by color channel and posting the pics, and it may be possible to guess at what kind of values to which they refer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the unwanted white pixels appearing like the one on the seats, you could use clamp indirect which is found in the light paths section or use clamp indirect which is found in the sampling section or you could even try using the denoiser which is in the render layer tab.