# Image Editor and Render Panel ... Pixel Click Color Information

Tags: rendering, interface, color, color-management

When a Blender User Clicks on a Render or an Image the user interface show RGBA info.

Please see image below.

There are two pieces of information. One is marked [CM].
Perhaps this is Color Management.

I internet searched for a documentation link to explain this information ... I could not find it.

Is there a documentation link to explain this information? Can it be provided?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there are quite a few answers already on this site, but just to summarize while the correct duplicate shows up: On the left is Scene Referred values, on the right (CM) are the values after the color management transforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do these numbers mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123496/what-do-these-numbers-mean)

Comment: No. It definitely does not answer my question. I asked for a link to Blender Documentation.  The link  provided in a comment also uses many terms not explained.  I will wait for a more explanatory answer.  I am requesting a link because there is a possibility there will be a more complete explanation with links.

Comment: Documentation is useless, but here it is: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/introduction.html#main-view

Comment: Which terms are unfamiliar to you?

Comment: [How to see RGB and XYZ image info in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/how-to-see-rgb-and-xyz-image-info-in-blender-2-8/134637#134637)