# How do I stop my white background from becoming grey due to lighting?

Tags: rendering, shaders, light

I'm trying to make a 3D rendered shot of my product model. I want the background to be plain white.
However, when I use a plain without material, it's greyish, depending on the lighting. If I use a material on the plane, there are artifacts/fireflies on my product model.

What's the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Under "*render properties* > *film*" you can flag the "*Transparent*" to have the word background transparent. In this way the render is a transparent image and you can put in background anything you need (in external photo editor or in blender too using the composite nodes).

[image]

Comment: This methods makes my lose the shadow though, doesnt it?

Comment: yes, if you remove the plane you'll loose the shadows. If you want shadows, you need to have the plane and add a little bit of emission shader to it, so It can emit lights and it's more white. Otherwise you should check "studio light" tutorials, that help you to understand what settings you need to have a good soft lights that don't "burn out" your mesh, but fill the background with smooth white.

Comment: or use a "shadow catcher", so that the plane is transparent and the shadows are projected on it.

Answer (score 2):

"*it's greyish, depending on the lighting*".
Indeed the solution is exactly in that statement. Use brighter sources and the "gray" can look like white.

Just increase the "power" of the lamps, or use a higher number than 1 on the strength (if you are using nodes)

Comment: But then my object catches a lot of light as well and doesnt look like it want it to look. Or shall I point the light away from the object?

Comment: "a lot of light" is not necessary, just bright enough to make the white surface look "white".

Comment: Read this link to understand how to evaluate the brightness of your scene: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175103/make-texture-visible-in-sunlight/175110#175110