# How to make a mesh look like glass

Tags: mesh, glass, reflection

I want to make a cube look like made out of glass. I know how to give it transparency but I don't know how to make it reflect light like glass in real life do

(Blender version 2.9)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to specify whether you want it to be realistic (in Cycles) or realtime (in Eevee)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a glass shader.

> The Glass BSDF is used to add a Glass-like shader mixing refraction and reflection at grazing angles. Like the transparent shader, only pure white will make it transparent
> Color
> Color of the surface, or physically speaking, the probability that light is ransmitted for each wavelength
> Roughness
> Influences sharpness of the refraction; perfectly sharp at 0.0 and smoother with higher values.
> IOR
> Index of refraction (IOR) defining how much the ray changes direction. At 1. 0 rays pass straight through like transparent; higher values give more refraction.
> Normal
> Normal used for shading.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/glass.html?highlight=glass

[image]

For reflections, set something in the scene or the environment that will be reflected on the surface.

Read:

[How to turn off reflections on glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205050/how-to-turn-off-reflections-on-glass/205061#205061)