# Freestyle Background color not white?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, freestyle

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFDrevyvmH8) and I've set my compositor up in the exact same way as he did, except my background is like a slightly light grey and I don't know why.  In his video's he's getting a bright white as his background and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Here's the render:
[image]

Here's the compositor window:
[image]

[Here's the blender project](https://www.pastefile.com/1xCBiJ) file.

Please help! I really want to know why it's not happening.

Comment: that .blend crashes my stable 2.79b Windows Blender with Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 8 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: @rob It's blender 2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the filmic color management option. If you switch back the view transform to default, you get full white as background.

Filmic allows values higher than 1.0, so 1.0 is not displayed (and exported) as full white.

Another way is to crank up lighting or emission values, to reach about 16, which is where filmic outputs pure white.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! This is totally the answer to my question.

Comment: So can you NEVER use filmic and get a pure white background ? If so it would probably be best to render it with an alpha layer and do some post processing in After effects right ?

Comment: In Filmic the light level of pure white is about 16, so you can have pure white, but you have to crank up your lighting system. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im/46940#46940