# Incorrect white background in compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

Really straight forward question here, basically I have a few doors I want to render with an alpha layer and a shadow catcher, then I want to use the compositor to add in a PURE white background ( HEX: FFFFFF ).

Even though I have a pure white selected in the compositor when I render it and use a color tester it is quite a bit less than PURE white ...

Must be missing something simple I guess ?

Here is my compositing setup ( you can see my HEX code ):
[image]

Here is my test of the result ( which is not pure white ):
[image]

Comment: `Render Properties/Color Management/View Transform/Raw` or  `Standard`?

Comment: Hello :). This answer should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/142693/

Comment: Big thanks to both Bruno and Jachym Michal ! 

I was able to switch my " look " control ( under color management ) to " none " and then I got a perfect white backdrop.

Comment: It actually did! surprised I did not find that when I was searching! ... so what do I do ... I wanted to give you the right answer but you submitted a comment ...

Comment: @CameronT0101 Just upvote the linked answer, and this question will be eventually marked as a duplicate :). To keep the site nice and tidy.

Comment: Ok ... now my question is does my post still live on ? Perhaps I used different words that others might easily find to help spread available paths to the correct answer, no ?