# Filmic Blender in Unity

Tags: unity, filmic-blender

If I make something in Blender with Filmic Blender. Save as asset, import it to Unity Game Engine... Wonder if the asset looks the same in Unity (with Filmic settings).

In other words, is Filmic only for Blender rendering?

Thanks,
Ondra

Answer (score 2):

Filmic is only for rendering. It how the colours are saved to the rendered image. You should look into HDR rendering in Unity to get something similar.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so... And thank you for HDR tip.

Answer (score 1):

Filmic Blender works by encoding a render scene for a certain type digital output written for a specific display screen. Classic Blender sRGB is an encoding type for the very-outdated old-fashioned CRT television. So if you are not using filmic Blender, your renders are being preset to be showed on a CRT. However, filmic blender does not change anything about the objects' materials. So if you switch to EEVEE, the *scene* will not change in terms of modeling, but the final render *will* look different.

Comment: Filmic blender is a series of transforms, where the scene's values (in linear data) will be encoded to be displayed in an sRGB display. The main difference with standard sRGB, is that sRGB will only use values from 0 to 1, whereas the Filmic transforms will deal with a  scale that is much larger. On top of that filmic makes the values that are very bright go towards white so that they look like overexposure on a camera. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Answer (score 0):

Filmic is a library of color look-up-tables. It doesn't affect anything but output image data, and the display in the 3D view. Filmic affects the way Blender displays colors in images that are rendered, composited, or created with the video sequence editor. AFAIK it isn't possible to apply view transform to baked images, though, so if you'd like to apply Filmic view transform to your textures, load them into the compositor and save them to files.

It might also be possible to customize the lookup tables that your game engine uses, but that's a topic for their forum.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so... And thank you for compositor tip.

Comment: @Joseph, it's not a library of look up tables. It's how scene colours are written onto the "digital negative", the rendered image. On top of that you can add lookup tables or colour adjustments as you like.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference. Isn't what you state just a second stage of LUT? How can I make my answer more accurate?

Comment: All this is a little bit too complicated to distill down to something understandable on a  comment line. https://www.creativeshrimp.com/filmic-blender-tutorial.html