# Images as emitters constantly come out dull. White emission not actually white. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine, emission

I have been using Blender for a while but keep hitting this problem that I don't understand.  First of all, I don't understand why I white emission shader set to pure white is not actually white unless I blast up the strength to at least 10.

[image]

This is fine if something is just white, but if I want an image to show up, I cannot increase the strength without blasting out the image.  For example, I downloaded this smiley face and brought it into Blender, and then changed to an emitter.  How do I get it to look like the actual photo that I downloaded?

[image]

Help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 10):

Set the color management as standard instead of filmic, and read this answer for detailed infos.

[Render with a wider dynamic range in cycles to produce photorealistic looking images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im/46940#46940)

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!! <3

Comment: If useful, please mark the answer as "accepted" (v sign).

Comment: @joshsanfelici it is easy to keep the filmic blender transforms. You just have work on the correct scale. "White" is not at 1.0 but around a value 16.29. If the emissions are set to that number they will be "white"

Comment: @cegaton Thanx for this useful information, I'm more expert in rigs than colors!