# 'image as plane' is always low quality than the original image

Tags: rendering, uv, armature, image, color

How can I render 'image as plane' with the same quality as original image?
The quality of image is always blurred and has a faint color.

This is how I did it.

(*Increased the resolution of the original image to 300 in Photoshop)

Open on image as 'image as plane'

Go to Material Properties

surface - emission

texture - image texture

image open

ㅡㅡ

Render for high results

Render 64 -> 128

Resolution x,y axis *2 / percent 100% -> 500%

output png quality 90% -> 100%

But the result image is a blurry than the original.

[image]

[image]

A is the original image. B is the rendered image. The image upload limit here make difficult to distinguish. But there are obvious differences

Worse for white background textures.
I used the same method as above.
White color turns into gray after rendering.(B)
So I adjust the Hue / Saturation to sharpen the color, but it is still blurry.(C)

[image]

I have tried few other things with uv mapping and shading (RGB Curves ..) but image as plane is always low quality than reference or background image.

What did I miss?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white/164679#164679