# PNG darker that the actual rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color, color-management

when I save my image as a png, it appears darker than the original rendering, or at least, the colorimetry is not the same. Does anyone have any idea what it is? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white/164679#164679

Comment: There's possibly a setting you can change in your render settings under colour to fix this. Otherwise, since you are on mac and using image preview you can always just click the pencil and then adjust settings pyramid button to correct the output.

Comment: Duplicated question. [Colorimetry is not the same](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195210/colorimetry-is-not-the-same)