# Colorimetry is not the same

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, color, color-management

I wanted to know if you know why the colorimetry of the image is not exactly the same when I save the image of the rendering, my settings in the save are however the Blender standards (RGBA, Color Dept 8, Compression 15%). Thank you very much for your answers :)

[image]

Comment: Maybe check the Render > Color Management settings? Or share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You are on an Apple device. The chances are your display is **not** sRGB, so using the sRGB device would be wrong, and all of your work accordingly wrong.

Comment: Hey, how can i change the display setting to sRGB ?