# Washed out texture in render compared to tutorial

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting

Still very new to Blender. I am trying to follow one of the old Andrew Price's tutorials [about loaf modeling](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-realistic-bread).

Well, long story short, while I am using a texture provided for the tutorial it looks a little washed out while to my understanding I followed all steps correctly (more or less).

For example, here is my render and the render from the video:
[image]

I also have the impression that small details generated by the normal map are also less visible (probably because of the same higher total brightness of the image).

I am using v2.91 of Blender while the tutorial was made 8 years ago, so of course, there could be some differences, but in both cases the render engine is Cycles.

Nodes structure is quite basic:
[image]

Light is "sun" as in tutorial (+ Ambient Occlusion is off):
[image]

Decreasing the light's strength somewhat helps, but the problem here is more about saturation than brightness.

I've also tried re-saving the provided texture to sRGB png as suggested in [this pos](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/y87jr/avoiding_washed_out_image_textures_in_cycles/)t, which gave no result.

I've checked out other posts about "washed out texture" here but they seem to be irrelevant.

Do you have any ideas in which direction to search?

Comment: Hello :). New Blender versions can display wider dynamic range than 8 years ago. That's probably the main difference.

Comment: Try [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white).

Comment: try messing with the specular slider on the principled, you can also use an RGB curve or Hue/Saturation node to modify the base color -- I would be quite happy with that loaf :)

Comment: Ok, after reading a little the suggested posts about dynamic range in blender it starts to make sense. Thanks!