# How can I create accurate Colors and Emission for a computer screen model?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, emission

I'm trying to create a product shot with a computer and a screenshot of a webpage. I have some basic nodes set up, but the colors look washed out and dull. Lights are disabled, and I've set the background to transparent. Here is what it looks like[image: blender snapshot]

Here's the screenshot of the webpage:

[image: webpage screenshot]

Upon first glance the color might look pretty similar, but the white on the computer screen definitely isn't #FFFF, and in my file Which I'll attach, you'll see what I mean. Can anyone point me to the best nodes to get a good looking computer screen with accurate colors and some nice light emission?

Thank you!!

[edit] removed "add shader" [image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you have an add shader connected to only one input in your graph. That will definitely wash out the colors.

Comment: Hi there, thanks, i just removed the add shader (it was cuz i was trying other things with it.) but the result now is just the same as before. I'll try to upload another screenshot if needed.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white

Comment: @scurest THANK YOU!