# Colors will change in scene when I use RGB node as shader

Tags: materials, shaders, color, shader-nodes

I am trying to create a scene with absolute no shading and depth. I created a basic material using nodes in the shading tab. I connected the color output from an RGB node with surface at material output. It looks wrong in the material prview and render using evee or cycles.

[image: Blender Window]

On the screenshot I am using Blender 2.92.0 using evee on default settings to render.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, that you can change the at "Render Propeties">"Color Management">"View transform" from Filmic to Standard.
I don't need further awnsers.