# Blender: how can I render true color?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting, color

I need to render images maintaining its original colors.

Here you can see the png (with transparent background) image on the project
[image]

Here a frame of the output:
[image]

Here the packed .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rdJcS2ETgy_hzEIbrSRvXuCSXu8I4zz1/view?usp=sharing

Other infos

- I'm using blender 2.83
- The rendering engine is set to eevee (film: transparent).
- There is a sun (color white, strength and specular 1.000, angle 0°, no shadows)
- There is a .png image (with transparency and material properties → settings → blend mode "alpha blend" and shadows mode "none") with followings nodes:
  [image]

thanks!

Comment: are you talking about a difference between Material Preview and Render Preview? It's normal, you're not supposed to see the same result. If you're talking about a difference between Render Preview and real render, it may be caused by the Color Management settings

Comment: I can't see how your nodes are set up, so maybe you've already done this, but have you tried connecting your image output(s) directly to the Material Output (without a shader), OR tried connecting them through an Emission Shader with a strength of 1?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. Mark the answer that 
helped you as accepted instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBQh7.png). 
Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Read also: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images as emitters constantly come out dull. White emission not actually white. What am I doing wrong?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white)

Answer (score 1):

When I open the file, I can see that you are in *Material Preview* mode. *Material Preview* mode gives you a preview but don't take your world and light setups into account, so the render won't look like what you currently see, you'd better switch to *Rendered Preview* to have a better idea of what you'll see as final result.

Also in the *Render panel > Color Management > View Transform*, you're in *Filmic* mode, it will make a rather pale render, switch to another mode, like *Standard*, if you want something closer to your original picture, unless you have good reasons to be in *Filmic*, of course.

At last, in *Rendered Preview* mode, you'll find that your image is still rather pale, it's because your sun has a *Strength* value of only 1. You can either increase it up to about 4, or plug your *Image Texture* into an *Emission* node, and mix it with a *Transparent* node (maybe it's possible to use the *Emission* of the *Principled BSDF* but anyway my setup works). With *Emission*, your image in the 3D scene will look exactly as it is:

[image]

Comment: It works! I can't vote because I've not 15 reputations.

Comment: no problem.....  ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the rendered version of a texture has the same color as the texture file, in the Shading tab, connect the texture output to the Material Output node without a shader.

Comment: i think this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful