# How to slowly fade out an image/plane? [solved]

Tags: mesh, transparency

I've an image with this properties:
[image: plane properties]
How can I do so that it's slowing disappearing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you can use principled bsdf instead of those nodes and use alpha value... you give alpha value 1, set keyframe and set another keyframe with value 0 to make it disappear over span of those keyframes

Comment: Hi I need this nodes for other reasons ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234516/blender-how-can-i-render-true-color )

Answer (score 3):

Just use a Maths node to manipulate the Alpha channel. You can either set it to Add or Subtract and ensure you have the Clamp checkbox enabled (so you don't get out of range) or you can use it as a Multiply and change the value of the multiplication between 1.0 (for 'normal' alpha) down to zero (for completely transparent).

[image: nodes]

Comment: It works for me! thanks

Comment: @SteZano Great - glad to be able to help. You can mark this answer as the 'Accepted' one by clicking the 'tick' just below the voting buttons on the left of the answer. This will help othersto find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the difference between these 2 pictures?
[image]

One uses your setup, one uses principled BSDF

My setup for it is this:
[image]

You can then animate it using this value:
[image]

0 is visible, 1 is invisible

Comment: ok, thanks I'll try. But how can I add the "subtract" chart?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRgKI.png

Comment: It is called "Math" node, you can then select Substract in the menu that you can open above the "clamp" button

Comment: Lighting conditions can overbrighten the Principled. With even light it will not be very noticeable, especially when seperated; I dare you to feed both into a Shader to RGB, then 
 Vector Subtract followed by Absolute.

Comment: I  don't think this is absolutely right... using the Principled BSDF for pure emission you shouldn't connect to the Base Colour and should instead set it to pure black - otherwise you'll get a surface response from incident light rather than pure emission as described in the original question.

Comment: I try your option @MikoGC but with value = 1 the transparent background becomes black and the image grey (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjC0S.png) - am I somehow wrong?