# Why do low resolution textures with the "Closest" setting look discolored?

Tags: rendering, texturing

so I like making low poly models with low resolution textures, but I always have a problem when it comes to rendering. See I'm aware that you can put the texture setting to "Closest", the dithering filter disappears and makes the pixels fully visible. However, when I switch to something like like material preview mode or any of the rendering modes, all the colors look washed out and not how I originally intended them to.
Is there any possible way I could fix this?

Here are a few pictures to explain what I mean:

[image: Solid viewport with flat shading, how it's meant to look.]

↑ Solid viewport with flat shading, how it's meant to look.

[image]

↑ Material preview & eevee, super bright, not at all what the colors are meant to be.
[image]

### ↑ Cycles and Workbench with flat shading, it's the closest to the original but the orange centre is still a little too yellow. It makes a greater difference on white textures with darker details.

[image]
Here's the texture

[image]
the emission

[image]
and the roughness

[image]
Here's the model put into blend exchange

[image]
Cycles with filmic (i'd paste the standard one but the post doesn't allow me)

Comment: Can you attach a .blend? Remember to pack the textures.

Comment: sure can, I've updated the post with the an example model and its corresponding textures.

Comment: Your blend file does not have the textures packed, you can pack the texture in menu File>External Data>Pack Resources. [Screenshoot](https://imgur.com/a/U3e37Cw)

Comment: Thanks! To get the colors to match Solid mode you'll need [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white). That said I don't see any color difference (definitely not from changing Closest) on my side. What do the eyeballs look like for you?

Comment: @scurest I've added what the models look with filmic, I couldn't add the last image with the standard view transform under color management, but it looks a whole lot more vibrant trust me. That being said, thank you so much for the help on this!