# Textures importing poorly into blender

Tags: texturing, import

I am trying to import this cork board texture into blender:

[image]

However when I import it onto a surface in blender, it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The original file is in .jpg format.

What can I do to improve the quality of the import?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: The color may be because of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/images-as-emitters-constantly-come-out-dull-white-emission-not-actually-white).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try looking in to some UV editing.