# Blender Object (Exported As FBX) Slightly Transparent And Poor Quality When Imported into Davinci Resolve

Tags: export, .fbx, compositing-nodes

I followed this tutorial by Blender Guru and finished creating a 3D donut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKPSB8tcXhQ

It was really good and looked photo realistic but for some reason when I exported the donut as an FBX object and put it in a Davinci Resolve 3D scene it looked poor quality and slightly transparent.

Here is the donut rendered in Blender (with the Cycles engine and a noise correction node):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3SME.jpg
Looks perfect!

Here is the donut after I exported it as an FBX object and put it in a 3D scene composited with real footage of my basement floor in Davinci Resolve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/psXtf.jpg
Looks really Bad...

So what and I doing wrong here? It seems like the textures are not getting exported correctly.

Comment: Please use the tools from this site to upload images,so that they show as part of your question and not as links. I see two options: 1st option is to composite directly in blender.  2nd option is to render the blender scene as OpenEXR and composite in resolve. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174098/i-have-tried-to-import-exr-files-to-davinci-resolve-with-the-luts/174228#174228 in any case there is no need to use FBX

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seems like this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174098/i-have-tried-to-import-exr-files-to-davinci-resolve-with-the-luts/174228#174228 is actually for rendering an image. I'm trying to create a stand alone 3D object and I'm planning on doing the compositing in Davinci. The problem is that the 3D object that I exported seems to be low quality and slightly transparent. Is there a way to export the whole object with the perfect photo-real quality that blender produces?

Comment: You are taking a baked material and rendering on a completely different color pipeline with completely different light values. You can't expect blender's cycles results from fusion.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. So I guess the best way is to just composite the footage in blender? Is there any way to export the object in a way that Davinci can recognize as identical?

Comment: Fusion is not a render engine. Blender is not a video editor. Don't use the software for what is not, but use the strengths of each one for what they are good at. Edit and color correct in resolve. Render in blender. You can do compositing in both, but, again it helps if you learn what each program can and cannot do.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following. So I should export the object from Blender right? And then import the object into Davinci? Right now I have been just going to File > Export > FBX with just the donut selected and clicking the checkbox "Selected Objects" and then importing the result into Davinci. Are there more steps on exporting a 3D object from Blender that I'm missing? Is there some kind of tutorial about how to do this?