# Export EXRs without supporting transmission and emission on the same pixels

Tags: rendering, emission, .exr

I'm trying to export my renders in EXR format for some further compositing in nuke, but noticed that the files exported as .exr look very different to the files exported as .png or the Blender preview.

After some searching, I found out that pngs are unable to correctly display emission and transmission for the same pixel, but that effect is actually what makes the crystals in my render look good, so in the .exr files, they look extremely flat.

Is there a way to export exrs in a way that would result in the same result as from the png file? (Aka force exrs to produce the same "error" for pixels with transmission and emission data)

PNG:
[image]

EXR:[image]

For reference, the EXRs contain these passes:
• Diffuse (Direct, Indirect, Color)
• Glossy (Direct, Indirect, Color)
• Transmission (Direct, Indirect, Color)
• Emission
• Object Cryptomatte

Comment: You have all the data from the render in the EXR files. What stops you from compositing the images any way you want? In any case, you have not provided enough information about what you are doing. What passes are you rendering, how are you compositing? What software?.. Please edit the question and provide full context. The question is not possible to answer as is. I am voting to close it based on it's current state.

Comment: I updated it with the information you requested :)

Comment: So you have Transmission and Emission passes. So what is stopping you from adjusting them whatever way you like? Another important thing to note is the fact that Blender saves color management transforms to png format, while EXR contains raw untouched data, so png images benefit from filmic color transform that might contribute to the look a lot with your scene. The fully saturated colors in light sources look quite unnatural. You might want to address that somehow in Nuke. [AgX](https://github.com/EaryChow/AgX) would help a lot here if you composited in Blender.

Comment: The issue is that the way PNG exports look is the result of a bug / limit of the file format, and I have no idea how to recreate the effect in the exr format, which is why I'm asking if there's a way to export a file making use of passes and layers while still getting the same look I get from the PNG limitations.

Comment: What PNG format bug are you referring to? I am not aware of any. Could you provide a link to the source of this information? Could you share an EXR file and a png file maybe?

Comment: Sure, here's the discussion that I found about it: 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png
And I showed the difference between the EXR and PNG in the original post already

Comment: I ask for EXR, to see the passes maybe understand a little better what is happening there.

Comment: "PNGs can't handle pixels that are emissive and transparent at the same time because PNG does not support associated alpha transparency." That actually makes no sense. "can't handle pixels" is not a thing. Alpha masks are not really suitable for mixing emission. Emission needs to be added to the image, not mixed with it. I think that is what he meant. It has little to do with PNG as a format. This also does not seem to be the problem in your case. I think what you see is different color management in Blender and in other software when viewing your EXR image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess without seeing the EXR file about what is happening:

The PNG file is saved with color management transforms baked to the image. In this case it is Filmic and it compresses high dynamic range especially the highlights. Also it should desaturate highlights slightly. And that's exactly what we see in the PNG compared to EXR in your provided images.

Your posted image of EXR looks like it lost detail in the highlights and highlights are completely saturated so that's maybe what could happen if you take the data in EXR and just display it as sRGB without any additional color transforms that would compress high dynamic range this way clipping all the highlights that do not fit. It looks like you need better color grading in Nuke. You could use Filmic color transform in Nuke as well since Nuke supports OCIO, or do whatever things that are done in Nuke to deal with issues like this that I do not know about since I don't use Nuke. To check if that is correct, just drag and drop the EXR in the Compositor in Blender, and have a look how it is displayed with regular Blender's Filmic color management. It should look the same as PNG since the EXR has all the data and nothing is actually lost there, but it is just displayed wrong in Nuke.

You could also do your compositing in Blender or at least consider it. This way you can be sure the colors you see in Blender will be the same during compositing without any extra trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)