# Blender Render Layers acting like a holdout when it shouldn't be

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, emission

I'm rendering out a tire with speed lines... In my view port everything looks fine but when rendering with the compositor and viewing the png my emission is masked when its not directly on top of the car mesh. I know I can solve this issue by just rendering the project out as one layer but I need 2 layers so I can later blur the Background in after effects.

I am using 2 render layers in this scene... a background "Racecar-Background" and a foreground "Racecar -Scene"

The speed lines become full transparent when its not overlapping with a mesh (this is the rendered image)
[image]

This is the render layer for my foreground "Racecar -Scene"
[image]

This is the render layer for my background "Racecar-Background"
[image]

This is my setup for the compositor
[image]

And just for optimal information this is the texture I'm using to create the lines but I'm pretty sure my issue is causes from the indirect toggle.
[image]

Any help would be amazing im sure its something simple im missing. :)

Comment: Have a look here [Render semi-transparent volume with cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles) and here [EXR color difference to PNG](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png) for the reasons you are having these problems. PNGs simply cannot handle emissive and/or semi-transparent materials over transparent backgrounds very well.