Volume emission and transparent background?
I have a problem with emission volume and transparent background
here is the file https://filebin.net/pm3hmhi3gvtdzxqs
I have a cube with emission volume and a transparent background but when I render the final image with cycles it doesn't show anything
Image in the render:

Final image saved

it is all white, no cube

It works fine for me, maybe a graphic card problem?

@moonboots thank you. I have updated the question. When I save the image, it appears completely white, instead are you able to see the cube?

oh ok I understand, actually it's a problem with transparency, you can't save such an image except with some tricks, see here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png or here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=tmb5HRU1cUohttps%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F41574%2Frender-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles

@moonboots, thank you. It is crazy man. I have to do an animation with 400 frames with bloom effect ... I can not do all this stuff together ... why don't they fix it?

Can't you do in the Compositor?
