# World displays as grey even though set to white

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I am using the 2D Animation preset and so far every new scene I made had the same bright white background. Now my two latest scenes (created with 'copy settings') have a light grey background even though they are set to white.
There's also **no difference in surface, nodes or strength.**

There are apparently exist different background shades with an off-white color but selecting the white one doesn't help either
[image]

Answer (score 4):

"White" is not an absolute value. The values change depending on the transforms  used in the color management section.

If you are using sRGB, with a sRGB view transform, white should be 1.

But If you are using filmic view transform, white is at a value of 16.29

The Color Management settings can be found in the Render Properties :

[image]

Comment: it is set to filmic; although I am not sure where to put the values you mentioned

Comment: in the "strength" values for the world.

Comment: To understand the difference read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46940/92768

Comment: @susu Hi. I saw you suggested an edit for the question. Tags are to describe the *question*, not possible answers.