# Gray background of world

Tags: shaders, world

When I render or when I use the verge3D app manager and open the model, the world background is gray and not white, even after setting the world color to white. I cant figure out what is doing this. This is what the background looks like:

[image]

The background should be completely white.

here is the blender file:
[image]

Comment: I might have uploaded without saving because I was exporting the file the whole time but, when you se the background to white it does make it a bit lighter but it does not make it completely white. I will reupload the file, thanks for the notice.

Comment: @lemon I cant find the setting mentioned there.

Comment: Render > Color Management > View Transform > Standard instead of Filmic

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175844/86891 I edited the answer to show where to find the setting

Comment: That fixed it! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly because of some lighting effects are happening in the scene. If you want a complete white background the I would suggest making the background first transparent and then adding a alpha over node in the compositer. If you want shadows as well,you can use a plane as a shadow catcher to add shadows in the scene with complete white background

Comment: Could you add screenshots to your answer? thanks

Comment: hey,okay,sending screenshots but you haven't found your answer yet