# Worse Megascans lighting compared to Unreal Engine

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting

I'm starting to learn Concept Art, creating my own scenes and so on. Of first I started using Unreal due to the conection it has with Quixel Megascans, being those free when used with Unreal. But then I realized that Blender maybe would be more suittable for the work I want to do, because of the features it has in modeling, particles, Cycles, etc, and maybe if I liked the workflow and the added features of Blender I would consider using it and subscribing to the Megascans subscription.

When I exported the first 3d asset from Quixel Bridge to Blender (it was a rock) I did not notice anything strange. But then I went and tried some of the snow assets, and the lighting in the asset textures was strange.
[image]
[image]
The images above shows the asset in Unreal Engine with and without the directional light activated. The Dynamic Exposure is desactivated.
[image]
Area Light Blender Eevee
[image]
Area light blender Cycles
[image]
Light off Blender Eevee
[image]
Light off Blender Cycles
[image]
Sun light Blender Eevee (in Cycles was almost the same)

[image]

Quixel Bridge sample foto

As you can see the lighting in Blender is nowhere near the Sample foto or Unreal, and in Cycles it should be even better. If you could help me solve this i would appreciate it a lot! I'm really really new to all of this, so maybe I'm missing some settings in Blender or I need to do something in the Shader Editor?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What you don't mention on your tests is how the color management is set up. For cycles, if you are use filmic and increase the energy for the lights so that you can make use of the wider dynamic range. Read: [Render with a wider dynamic range](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/)

Comment: Also remember to put an HDRI in the Environmental Texture node of the World shader. This is found by going into the Node Editor window, clicking the drop-down at the top that says "Object" and changing it to "World". You will see that an Environmental Texture node is already setup and is empty. Put an HDRI in there. That will completely change the lighting.