# Issue with color value when loading rendered image in GIMP

Tags: color, height-map

I want to create a height map in Blender, for use in an external program, with specific color values for the different height levels. But when I import the rendered image (saved as Tiff) in GIMP, the hex values are not the same anymore: they are slightly off.

Why is that so?

Comment: Sounds like bad colorspace conversion, or possibly you need to turn off Color Management.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154471/render-solid-color-in-eevee/154503#154503 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189916/output-tonemapping-to-png-produces-gray-even-for-superwhites/

Comment: Yep, I switched from filmic to standard, that solved the problem! Thx!