# Color looks mouch more saturated when in shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, color

I'm trying to setup kitchen scene. Currently playing with colors of the cabinets.

[image]

Scene is lighted through the windows (visible in reflections above), no indoor lighting yet.

I feel like color of left and top cabinets is not only darker, but also much more saturated than the bottom ones.

**Is this some kind of issue with lighting I have applied?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This is just how light works - 6000K is almost pure white, so any color directly under it looks a bit washed out. Items in shadows just keep more of the saturation.

Comment: I believe that this is filmic color management at work. Andrew Price did a video about it here: https://youtu.be/m9AT7H4GGrA?t=615  I cut to the part where he starts talking about filmic. (the feature comes with blender now)

Comment: @HISEROD I've now noticed how big diference it makes. Anyh suggestions shich will be the best? Raw, or standard maybe?

Comment: Filmic is the best for renderings that require good dynamic range (which is most of them). To increase the saturation, you can slightly decrease the exposure and/or change the contrast setting. The manual has some info about the other transforms: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render

Comment: Don't change the color management (not until you know what you are doing). Darker objects will tend to look more "colorful" than brighter ones, that is part of how we perceive things. The filmic color transform will make it so brighter objects will eventually become white (as when film is overexposed). Read:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Comment: Also keep in mind that surfaces are also influenced by the color of the light reflected by other objects around it.  Color is complex, as is also subjective: the same color (or brightness) can be perceived as a different one, depending on the color that is adjacent or around it.