# Setting background color

Tags: rendering, color, compositing-nodes

I am trying to set my background to be only one color.

Below is my 'Compositing' edit screen and the color i set for the background.

[image]
[image]
This is how it turned out :
[image]

So clearly its toned down so much, from neon pink to some gloomy ass CMYK red.
How can I set the background to be exactly the color I set in the compositing screen?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: can you upload a .blend? feel free to take out whatever as long as the error is still happening.

Comment: Check your Render Properties settings and try switching Color Management from "Filmic" to "Standard".

Comment: awesome, it did work :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Christopher Bennet,

1. Go to Render Properties
2. Go to Color Management
3. Change View Transform tab from "Filmic" to "Standard".

Beware this alters the color scheme of the whole render; it's like changing a filter on a picture in instagram. So if you are a designer or someone who is super color sensitive, gl

Comment: Hardly an answer... Filmic is not like an instagram filter. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im